# Why raspberry pi sometimes stalls after executing "vcgencmd get_camera " Command?

Tags: camera, raspicam, picamera, mmal

I frequently use vcgencmd get_camera  command on the raspberry pi, It gives the following error-

```
vc_gencmd_send returned -1
vchi_msg_dequeue -> -1(22)
```

And then raspberry pi hangs.
I then executed the following command-
sudo vcdbg log msg

I get the following log-
This is the sequence of events that are captured by vcdbg tool after executing

```
vcgencmd get_camera
sudo vcdbg log msg

001468.611: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/config.txt
001472.708: brfs: File read: 4595 bytes
001505.614: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 0
001506.880: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 1
001508.145: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 2
001509.408: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 3
001510.673: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 4
001511.938: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 5
001513.203: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 6
001514.466: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 7
001515.732: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 8
001516.996: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 9
001518.020: HDMI0:EDID giving up on reading EDID block 0
001519.800: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/config.txt
001522.437: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin LEDS_PWR_OK not defined
001715.681: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin DISPLAY_DSI_PORT not defined
001717.033: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin LEDS_PWR_OK not defined
001717.090: *** Restart logging
001717.116: brfs: File read: 4595 bytes
001718.320: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 0
001719.590: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 1
001720.858: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 2
001722.127: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 3
001723.394: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 4
001724.664: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 5
001725.932: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 6
001727.201: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 7
001728.468: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 8
001729.738: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 9
001730.764: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID giving up on reading EDID block 0
001731.095: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 0
001732.365: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 1
001733.634: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 2
001734.904: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 3
001736.171: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 4
001737.441: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 5
001738.709: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 6
001739.979: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 7
001741.246: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 8
001742.516: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 9
001743.542: hdmi: HDMI0:EDID giving up on reading EDID block 0
001743.835: hdmi: HDMI:hdmi_get_state is deprecated, use hdmi_get_display_state instead
001743.859: HDMI0: hdmi_pixel_encoding: 162000000
001744.125: vec: vec_middleware_power_on: vec_base: 0x7e806000 rev-id 0x00002708 @ vec: 0x7e806100 @ 0x00000420 enc: 0x7e806060 @ 0x00000220 cgmsae: 0x7e80605c @ 0x00000000
001745.027: kernel=
001752.734: dtb_file 'bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb'
001757.128: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
001757.151: Loaded 'bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb' to 0x100 size 0x7d8e
001772.166: brfs: File read: 32142 bytes
001787.233: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/overlays/overlay_map.dtb
001876.140: brfs: File read: 2347 bytes
001878.935: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/config.txt
001879.490: dtparam: audio=on
001886.216: dtparam: spi=on
001894.311: dtparam: i2c_arm=on
001903.313: dtparam: i2c0=on
001919.360: dtparam: i2c1=on
001934.533: brfs: File read: 4595 bytes
001935.340: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/cmdline.txt
001935.395: Read command line from file 'cmdline.txt':
001935.414: 'console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=57c9ce7f-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles'
001951.242: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin EMMC_ENABLE not defined
002568.058: brfs: File read: 125 bytes
002966.337: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/kernel7.img
002966.353: Loaded 'kernel7.img' to 0x8000 size 0x67ebe0
002966.378: Device tree loaded to 0x2eff7c00 (size 0x830d)
002971.879: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin SDCARD_CONTROL_POWER not defined
006749.383: vchiq_core: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xf4180000, is_master = 1
011537.171: camsubs: Looking for camera 0: i2c_port = 0, led gpio = 134, power enable gpio = 133
011832.827: camsubs: Camera not found
011832.923: camsubs: Looking for camera 0: i2c_port = 0, led gpio = 134, power enable gpio = 133
011834.531: camsubs: Camera found OK
2037961.329: mmal: mmal_port_event_send: event lost on port 1,0 (buffer header callback not defined)
2041814.021: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
2044585.965: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
2045758.621: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
2046434.487: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
2046935.509: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
308846.657: mmal: mmal_port_event_send: event lost on port 1,0 (buffer header callback not defined)
311757.300: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
314165.724: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
315328.380: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
315921.146: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
316305.855: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
604736.413: mmal: mmal_port_event_send: event lost on port 1,0 (buffer header callback not defined)
608865.168: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
611691.812: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
612854.009: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
613495.711: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
613985.760: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
2581861.243: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
2584944.266: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
2961077.573: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
2964141.652: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
3030729.998: mmal: mmal_port_event_send: event lost on port 1,0 (buffer header callback not defined)
3032887.677: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
3035355.466: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
3036489.581: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
3037025.335: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
3037392.853: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
3294449.260: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
3294543.218: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
3550194.029: mmal: mmal_port_event_send: event lost on port 1,0 (buffer header callback not defined)
3552420.983: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
3555750.171: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
3556890.074: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
3557471.523: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
3557835.313: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
3942123.149: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
3942205.497: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
1157023.262: mmal: mmal_port_event_send: event lost on port 1,0 (buffer header callback not defined)
1161383.096: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
1164277.121: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
1165439.846: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
1166125.112: mmal: mmal_vll_load: could not load VLL 'videnc.vll':
1166584.570: mmalsrv: send_buffer_to_host: tx failed:size 292 st -1
```

Then, if I try to reboot the pi , and again try to access the pi through putty , it gives network connection error and throw network connection error...Then I have to reset power the pi to access it again .. after reaccessing the pi after powerreset , I am able to perform vcgencmd get_camera without any problem

Comment: What OS? What Pi?

Comment: OS release--
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

PI Information-
Model           : Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2

Comment: Do not put detail in comments EDIT your question (and preferably tag with OS)

Answer (score 0):

Bullseye does not support [Picamera](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bullseye-camera-system/)

Install `libcamera`

Comment: I have enabled legacy camera, then it should be supported..There is certain reason that I want to use legacy camera